# When does PostUpdateEventListener get called when using @Transactional

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-transactions

I'm trying to figure out when `PostUpdateEventListener` is called when encapsulating the method with `@Transactional`. Let's say we have Entity X, and where the `@Transactional` method (Class A) calls another class (Class B) with the `@Transactional` method. Class B makes no modifications to Entity X, while Class A makes modifications before and after the call. When doing this I've noticed when debugging that custom-defined `PostUpdateEventListener` will get called immediately when the call is made to Class B's method, and also again at the end of Class A method. I've been trying to dig into how and when to expect this listener to get called, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Okay, so I may have found the cause of the earlier trigger. It seems to be the result of Class B having a query call that uses Container-Managed `EntityManager`, found this while digging. But I would still like to understand why that would cause this behavior exactly. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert, update or remove listeners are called before or after the actual flush. If you have an entity in your first-level/persistence context that is dirty (i.e. you changed data on it), then Hibernate will flush changes as late as possible, the latest point being before transaction commit.
If you query something, that reads from a table which would be affected by a flush, then Hibernate forcefully does that flush before executing the query and hence also executes certain listeners as part of that flushing.

Comment: Got it, that clears up what I am seeing then. So because the query that was fetching the data was including the table whose entity was dirty that is what is causing the forceful flush by Hibernate. Thank you very much for helping provide me with the context of what is going on!